# Does Google's PageRank count as a sorting algorithm?

Tags: algorithms, sorting

Is it correct to assume that PageRank is a sorting algorithm or does it fall in any other category?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer depends on what you mean by a *sorting algorithm*. The usual meaning is:

> A sorting algorithm is an algorithm that gets a list $L$ of comparable objects, and sorts them in (say) nondecreasing order. The algorithm could only work for a certain class of objects.

If you use this definition, then PageRank isn't a sorting algorithm. But it's up to you.

Comment: Thanks alot for the suggestion.

Comment: One may say that PageRank is a *ranking* algorithm, not a sorting algorithm.